# AttributeError: 'H1bInfo' object has no attribute 'K_meanAnalyze'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, decision-tree

```
def K_meanAnalyze(self,H1bInfo):
        #Get the states values
        worksites = H1bInfo['WORKSITE']
        H1City, H1State = worksites.str.split(', ', 1)
        
        #Reading Latitude and Longitude data (taking out null)
        H1LatLong = H1bInfo.loc[H1State != 'NA']
        H1LatLong = H1LatLong[['lon','lat']]
        H1LatLong = H1LatLong.dropna()
        H1Long = H1LatLong['lon'].values
        H1Lat = H1LatLong['lat'].values

        #K-Means clustering to see where the applicants were
        nClusters = 10
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=nClusters, random_state=0).fit(H1LatLong.values)
        #Getting the cluster for each case
        kl = kmeans.labels_
        H1LatLong['Cluster'] = kl
        H1LatLong['State'] = H1State
        H1LatLong = H1LatLong.dropna()
        return H1LatLong


if __name__ == "__main__":

    h1bSystem = H1bInfo()
    try:
        H1Info = pd.read_csv('h1b_history.csv')
    except IOError:
        print("Error: cannot find the path,pleas put data and program in the same folder")
    else:
        print("data file read successfully")

    function = 1
    k_meanResult = h1bSystem.K_meanAnalyze(H1Info)
```

I am working in google colab, I wrote this code and although I defined the function, I get the following error. I looked at the site but I couldn't find a similar error. How to solve it?

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-114-f029a4ae230e> in <cell line: 1>()
         10 
         11     function = 1
    ---> 12     k_meanResult = h1bSystem.K_meanAnalyze(H1Info)
         13 
         14     salary_Result = h1bSystem.salaryAnalyze(H1Info, k_meanResult)
    
    AttributeError: 'H1bInfo' object has no attribute 'K_meanAnalyze
```